# Recalculate points in an SVG path when first or last point changes

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have built a graph with D3.js based on [this example of a force-directed graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), but rather than having straight lines between the nodes I am creating curved lines using *SVG* *path* elements. The data structure for an individual link includes a *source* and *target* which represent the nodes to which the link is connected. Also the link data structure also contains a *line* element which contains an array of points defining the path. The data structure for a link looks like this:

```
{
    id:4,        
    type:"link", 
    fixed:true, 
    source: {
                id:1, 
                name: "A",
                type:"node", 
                x:226, 
                y:190, 
                fixed:1, 
                index:0, 
                weight:1, 
            }, 
    target: {
                id:2, 
                name: "B",
                type:"node", 
                x:910, 
                y:85, 
                fixed:1, 
                index:1, 
                weight:1, 
            }, 
    line:[{x:387, y:69}, {x:541.5, y:179}, {x:696, y:179}]
}
```

Now in my *on tick* event handler I have the current *x* and *y* co-ordinates for for nodes *A* and *B* by means of the references *d.source.x*, *d.source.y* and *d.target.x*, *d.target.y*. I also have the initial position of node A (first element of *d.line*) and of node B (last element of *d.line*). What I am trying to do is to recalculate the points in between the first and last points based on the changes made to the positions of nodes *A* and *B*.

Here is my *on tick* event handler:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
svg.selectAll("g.node").attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    svg.selectAll("g.link .line").attr("d", function(d) { 
         var xOffset = 0, // Want to calculate this 
             yOffset = 0; // Want to calculate this
         var line = [ ];
         for (var i=0; i<d.line.length; i++) {
             if (i==0) {
                  line[line.length] = { x : d.source.x, y: d.source.y }
             }
             else if (i==d.line.length-1) {
                  line[line.length] =  { x : d.target.x, y: d.target.y }
             }
             else {
                  line[line.length] = { x: d.line[i].x + xOffset, y: d.line[i].y + yOffset }
             }
         }
         return self.lineGenerator(line);
     })
 });
```

Not offsetting the *x* and *y* co-ordinates for the points in the middle of the path results in these points staying static when nodes A or B are dragged. Can anyone explain how to go about calculating *xOffset* and *yOffset* so that the path will correctly move/rotate when the nodes are dragged? Or if anyone knows of a better (read "easier"!) way of accomplishing this with D3.js then please let me know.

UPDATE:

Here is my line generator code in the chart constructor:

this.lineGenerator =  d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                .interpolate("cardinal");

Let me explain the problem with some images, hopefully they will make the problem that I am having clearer. It is not a matter of the lines being linear, my lines are curved by the line generator, but when I drag a node, I want the curve to drag as well. So all the points on the line must update to reflect the change made to the position of the node. In other words the path must not get distorted by the nodes being moved.

So, in pictures; given this situation:

[image]

If I drag node B down and to the left, I want to see something like this:

[image]

(Note that this was rotated with image editting software, hence the background is also rotated)

Instead I am getting something like this:

[image]

Note how the one intermediary point in the line has stayed static when node B was moved, causing the curve to distort. This is what I am trying to avoid happening.

Hopefully this makes the problem clearer.

Comment: You didn't give us the definition of your line generator, but it sounds like you're using straight line segments. It might be easier to use Bezier curves or something like that where the browser will compute intermediate points automatically. More details on the commands available for SVG paths [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html).

Comment: (After update) It sounds like what you want to do should be done in the line generator. That is, rather than try to move intermediate given points, calculate them dynamically in the line generator. Presumably you've used something like this to compute the intermediate points in the first place?

Comment: No, the curve of the line is not calculated in the first place, it is created by the user. If you look at the elbow join you will see a faint round circle, these highlight red when the user hovers on them and allows them to drag the line. The user can add new points to the path and then drag them to create the required path. When the nodes are dragged though, this path created by the user must not distort. I don't know of a way to use the line generator to recalculate the intermediary points based on changes made to the first and last point in the path.

Comment: So in other words, in the example that I gave I am not needing to calculate ALL the points in the new curve, I want to know how to calculate the new position of the ONE point; the one at the elbow joint. Once I have that correctly moved I can then recalculate all the other points with the line generator.

Comment: Hmmm, so you basically want to apply the same translation as to the point that the user moved to the elbow point? Have you tried doing it simply like that?